# More accurate indexing

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, subdomain

I need to remove some pages from indexing but i still need to index subdomain links.

I have this website structure

```
/ -- main page
/region/ -- regions
/region/1 -- specific region with cities and links to %city-name%.example.com
```

How can i remove (region, region/id) from indexing but keep indexing links with subdomains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using `noindex, follow` is not going to last. Over time Google will inevitably treat it as `noindex, nofollow`. Here's a [Search Engine Roundtable post from 2017](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-long-term-noindex-follow-24990.html) on the subject.

It would be easier to handle this at the server level, rather than using meta tags. You can just leave out the `follow`.

#### Nginx

```
location /region/ {
    add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex";
}

location /region/1 {
    add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex";
}

# or rather
location ~ ^/region/ {
    add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex";
}
```

#### Apache

```
<LocationMatch "^/region/">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this question by adding the following to meta data.

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow"/>
```